# ¿Como guardar 0 y 1 con un checkbox?

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos, checkbox

Tengo un campo que se llama estado y esta con atributo boolean, quiero guardar en la base de datos cuando el input este en estado checked que guarde el valor 1 y el otro que guarde 0, ¿Tienen alguna duda de como hacerlo, hay que hacer con ajax, o hay otra forma de realizarlo? estoy trabajando con laravel 5.2.

Muchas Gracias.

```html
<div class="switch">
<label>INACTIVO<input type="checkbox" checked><span class="lever"></span>ACTIVO</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que necesitaras utilizar **JavaScript** y enviar por `AJAX` la información, ya que el valor predeterminado de un `checked` no es `1/0` por lo cual habría que convertir su valor a número de la siguiente forma:

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
  $(this).val(Number(this.checked));
  
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="switch">
<label>INACTIVO<input type="checkbox" checked><span class="lever"></span>ACTIVO</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, me sirvió mucho.